# JS Keep loading till img src changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, src

I want to monitor an unmount event on my NAS.
it has a seperate page to unmount all usb drives.
I've included it via iframe and want to keep the site loading until the image source has been changed to a specific source (a green bar, indicating that it has done unmounting).
The reason why I want to keep it loading is because im calling it via a jquery.get function from another site, and i want it to wait till the unmounting process is done.
Would be great if this is possible only in plain javascript, but if needed I can also include jquery.
Here is what I got so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check(){
if (!(document.getElementById("uiView_TestPic").src == "/css/default/images/finished_ok_green.gif")){
window.setTimeout(check(), 2000);
}else{
alert("Done!");
}}
window.onload(check());
</script></head>
<body>
<iframe seamless width="100%" frameborder="0" height="80%" src="http://fritz.box/usb/usb_diskcut.lua?usbdev=all"></iframe>
```

I am immediately receiving an error that the element "uiView_TestPic" does not exist, even when I add a timeout before running check.

The included iFrame site stops loading as soon as all images are loading and not when the whole process is done.

Comment: is `#uiView_TestPic` inside the iframe?

Comment: If `uiView_TestPic` is in a different iframe than where the JS is running, then you have to get the document from the iframe and use that `document` with `getElementById()`.  Your current code is searching your current document, but the pic is in a different document.

Comment: how to make JS look in the iframe document?

Comment: @user1685565 - I added an answer for how to look in the iframe document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, both frames must be running on the same domain because browsers will prevent code in one frame from accessing anything in the other frame if they are different domains.  If the two frames are not on the same domain, then the iframe will have to monitor itself and notify the other frame when it has finished using something like [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage).

If they are on the same domain, this is slightly complicated.  You have to get the iframe element (that's in your main document).  You have to wait for that to be ready (since it has to load it's own contents).  Then, you have to get the document in the iframe.  Then you can find the desired image in the iframe.  Then you can observe it's contents. And, of course, you can only do any of this if the iframe is the same domain as your main page (because of security restrictions).

First, add an id to the iframe:

```
<iframe id="myFrame" seamless width="100%" frameborder="0" height="80%" src="http://fritz.box/usb/usb_diskcut.lua?usbdev=all"></iframe>
```

Then, you can use this:

```
    // put this code in your document AFTER the iFrame tag
    // or only run it after the DOM is loaded in your main document

    function checkImageSrc(obj) {
        if (obj.src.indexOf("/finished_ok_green.gif") !== -1) {
            // found the green gif
            // put whatever code you want here
        } else {
            // check repeatedly until we find the green image
            setTimeout(function() {
                checkImageSrc(obj);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    // get the iframe in my documnet
    var iframe = document.getElementById("myFrame");
    // get the window associated with that iframe
    var iWindow = iframe.contentWindow;

    // wait for the window to load before accessing the content
    iWindow.addEventListener("load", function() {
        // get the document from the window
        var doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

        // find the target in the iframe content
        var target = doc.getElementById("uiView_TestPic");
        checkImageSrc(target);
    });
```

FYI, there's more detail on waiting for an iframe to be ready here: [How can I access the DOM elements within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe/24603642#24603642)

---

If you control the code in the iframe, then a much cleaner way to implement this would be to use [`window.postMessage()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.postMessage) to post a message to the parent window when the code in the iframe finishes its operation.  Then the parent window can just listen for that single message and it will know when the operation is done.

That could look something like this.  Put this code in the iframe:

```
    // put this code in your document AFTER the relevant image tag
    // or only run it after the DOM is loaded in your iframe

    // if you can hook into the actual event that knows the unmount
    // is done, that would be even better than polling for the gif to change

    function checkImageSrc(obj) {
        if (obj.src.indexOf("/finished_ok_green.gif") !== -1) {
            // found the green gif
            // notify the parent
            window.parent.postMessage("unmount complete", "*");
        } else {
            // check repeatedly until we find the green image
            setTimeout(function() {
                checkImageSrc(obj);
            }, 2000);
        }
    }

    // find the target in the iframe content
    var target = document.getElementById("uiView_TestPic");
    checkImageSrc(target);
```

Then, in your main window, you would listen for the posted message like this:

```
    window.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
        // make sure this is coming from where we expect (fill in the proper origin here)
        if (e.origin !== "http://example.org:8080") return;
        if (e.data === "unmount complete") {
            // unmount is complete - put your code here
        }
    });
```

Comment: well, they do not have the same domain. the website is running of my raspberry pi (locally) and the other one is my router. That might be the reason why your code does not work for me, I added a simple alert after the img src changed but nothing happens. maybe there is another way? maybe even without an iframe? it was just the first and simplest method I can think off to call a website and wait for the img src to be changed

Comment: @user1685565 - Hmmm, that's an important detail that wasn't in your question.  Browsers prevent ANY access from one frame to another if they are running on separate domains.  As I said at the end of my answer, if you control both sites, then just have the iframed website use `window.postMessage()` to it's parent window when the image changes.  `window.postMesssage()` is allowed between frames with a different domain, but that is all that is allowed.

Comment: @user1685565 - I added an example using `window.postMessage()` for cross origin frames.

Comment: unfortunately its part of the router's OS, no way I could edit it. That means that there is no way to make it work?

Comment: @user1685565 - There is no way to get to the iframe DOM from outside of the iframe when it's a different domain.  I don't think you can monitor the GIF from the outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the element is there in the dom or not and then have the check for the src. Something like this should work:

```
function check(){
if (document.getElementById("uiView_TestPic") && !(document.getElementById("uiView_TestPic").src == "/css/default/images/finished_ok_green.gif")){
window.setTimeout(check(), 2000);
}else{
alert("Done!");
}}
window.onload(check());
```

In this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pLT6Y/) you will see that src null error is not happening. However if you remove document.getElementById("uiView_TestPic") && you get your error

Comment: Hm, now I immediately receive the Done alert, even when the site did not even finish loading. (Im upvoting your post to get you back to 0 :P)

Comment: Because `#uiView_TestPic` is not in the same document, `document.getElementById("uiView_TestPic")` will never find it (it's looking in the wrong document).  One has to wait for the iframe to load, then get the document from the iframe, then get the element from that document, then see if it's the right image.