# Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': timing issue?

Tags: javascript, iframe, innerhtml, timing

Others have encountered a similar error, usually because they tried to access a DOM object before a web page had completely loaded. I am doing something different, but I may also have a timing problem.

I have a Javascript application that communicates with CGI scripts with forms and iframes. The first time the user clicks a submit button, the JS application creates an invisible iframe and sends the form's data to the server. The server is supposed to respond by sending data to the iframe which the JS application reads and interprets.

Here is a very simplified version of the code:

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe");
iframe.name = "myIframe";
document.body.appendChild(iframe);
var iframeDocument = 'contentDocument' in iframe? iframe.contentDocument : iframe.contentWindow.document;
iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = "";
```

The full error is: TypeError: Unable to set value of the property 'innerHTML': object is null or undefined

The entire page loaded long ago--when the code above executes, the user has entered some data and hit a submit button. However, the iframe is new.

The code works fine on my computer--I cannot reproduce the problem. I can see from a log file on the server that the user agent is 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)'.

Perhaps naively, I thought that the iframe had been created and I could set its document's innerHTML property. Could this be a timing problem? Do I have to wait before setting innerHTML, or is something else going wrong?

If the error is indeed caused by a timing problem, I can probably fix it by creating the iframe when the page first loads. If the user then clicks a cancel button, the iframe will never be used--I thought it was better to create the iframe only when it is needed. To really fix this error, I have to understand it--that is why I am asking my question.

Comment: The code in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe/24603642#24603642) will let you know when an iframe is "ready".

Comment: Is the `src` attribute of the `iframe` set to anything? Also, and I'm merely curious, is there an advantage of you using this method to get the server response (as opposed to using AJAX or something similar) or is this an example for learning purposes?

Comment: Pete, I'm not setting the src attribute of the iframe I created. I don't want to send an unnecessary request to the server. In regards to Ajax, I've read a little about it but haven't used it--I can't make a valid comparison.

Comment: Freez, thanks for your suggestion. I tried it but it had an unwanted side effect: the iframe's onload function executed every time data was sent from the server to the iframe, and setting iframeDocument.body.innerHTML to the empty string wiped out that data. So the server sent data, the onload function cleared it, and the application hung waiting for the server's data :-). I decided to use the onload function just to set the variable iframeDocument. I now clear the innerHTML property only on the second and subsequent uses of the iframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's a timing issue, you can try :

```
var iframe = document.createElement("iframe"),
    iframeDocument;
iframe.name = "myIframe";

iframe.onload = function(){
    iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;
    iframeDocument.body.innerHTML = "";
};

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

That way you'll be sure that your iframe will be ready