# How to access cross-domain iframe wrapping contents

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I have an `<iframe>` like this-

```html
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://www.producthunt.com/" width="800" height="600" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

I want to get the wrapping names of "div" in that product hunt website.
Let's say product hunt website have a div name "products", How to I get that? For example, If a user click on a  tag , I want to know that user clicked a  tag or

tag etc

I  know it's a basic question, but please help me.

Comment: Are you trying to change the HTML inside the `<iframe>`?

Comment: @Andrew yeah kind of. But I need that wrapping names. For example, If a user click on a <h1> tag , I want to know that user clicked a <h1> tag or <p> tag etc

Comment: read this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6170925/get-dom-content-of-cross-domain-iframe

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access the DOM elements within an iFrame](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe)