# Get and print hash in iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Want to get hash from this url

```
http://www.mywebsite.com/#/aaaaaaaa
```

**aaaaaaaa**

**And add to iframe :**

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com/url/aaaaaaaa" frameborder="0">
```

**Javascript code :**

```
<script>
var hhash = window.location.hash.substr(1);
alert(hhash);
</script>
```

Comment: And? What is wrong with the code you already have? I.e. what is your question? Also, you want to add the hash to the iframe, or rather to the src of the iframe?

Comment: yes , @Teemu i want to print "aaaaaaaa" automatically in iframe with javascript

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe Althought, it looks like you're misusing `location.hash`, maybe you should use a query string instead?

Comment: Thank you for your time @Teemu but i cant edit this code , I'm Beginner in javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also use the lastIndexOf() function to locate the last occurrence of the / character in your URL, then the substr() function to return the substring starting from that location:

```
 var hhash =(window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1));
 document.write("<iframe src=\"example.com/url/\""+hhash+"frameborder=\"0\">");
```

Comment: Thank you @Osama , but i want to print var hhash .. "aaaaaaaa" in iframe like this <iframe src="http://www.example.com/url/aaaaaaaa" frameborder="0">

Comment: Thank you very much mr Osama

Comment: This won't write valid HTML.

Comment: It will only check the syntax of the document.write() line I use my iPhone not the laptop so may be an error there

Answer (score 0):

Your title and question is a little bit misleading.
If you just want to print the hash tag, you can create an element and set the `innerText` to your hash, like so:

```js
// Use hash instead of href here! :) This is just to make the example work
const lastPart = window.location.href.split( '/' ).pop();
document.querySelector( '.hash' ).innerText = lastPart;
```

```html
<div class="hash"></div>
```

---

If you want to alter the src of the iFrame, you could use the first example combined with setAttribute.

```js
// Use hash instead of href here! :) This is just to make the example work
const lastPart = window.location.href.split( '/' ).pop();
const src = 'http://example.org/url/' + lastPart;
document.querySelector( '.hash' ).setAttribute( 'src', src );
document.querySelector( '.url' ).innerText = 'iframe points to ' + src;
```

```html
<iframe class="hash"></iframe>
<div class="url"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your time , but i want just to print last folder http://www.mywebsite.com/#/aaaaaaaa .... "aaaaaaaa"  in iframe like this <iframe src="http://www.example.com/url/aaaaaaaa" frameborder="0">

Comment: My second example should do exactly that

Comment: What does not work (any errors?) and what is your expected outcome?

Comment: Blank page , I cannot get  "aaaaaaaa" in iframe

Comment: Ok so your real iframe also loads example.com? I thought the page you are loading already checks for the location.
If you just want to show the hash on your page, you don't need to have an iframe. Just go with the first solution by adding a `<div class="hash"></div>` :) Otherwise you need to explain a little more what you want exactly

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed explanation  Mr.lumio

Answer (score 0):

You can get hash part (without `#/`) with:

```
var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#/', '');
```

Then you get the current iframe `src` attribute with :

```
var src = document.getElementsById('YourIframeId').getAttribute('src');
```

And now you update the iframe `src`:

```
document.getElementsById('YourIframeId').setAttribute('src',src + '/' + hash);
```