# Can't manipulate content of iframe with Google Chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, iframe

i'm working on project where there is a twenties of animation in generated pages. this pages are embedded into iframes of the index page. And i have to add elements to these pages (under the same project) via iframes contents. To simplify things i've tried first to change the iframe body background or add a simple tag to the iframe body. it works with firefox but not with chrome !

```
// works with firefox but not with chrome
$('#frameId').load( function(e) {
     alert('loading');
     $('#frameId').contents().find("body").append($("<h1>someThing</h1>"));
});
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access the DOM elements within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome has default security restrictions that don't allow you to access other windows from the hard disk even though they are technically the same origin.
[Here is your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe)

Comment: thanks a billion vote if i could worked on local web server.