# Detect when iframe has finished loaded with nodejs

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, iframe

I have an embedded iframe in a page. It loads much slower than the rest of the page so I'd like to access it when its finished loading.

The end goal is to change the css inside the iframe via jquery. Atm, the css file completes loading before the iframe so the changes are not being applied.

Would this be able to be done? Will i need to use node's 'complete'? I'm a noob to node and just getting into promises and the .then() functionality.

Comment: This has nothing to do with node.js at all.  This is all client-side.  Some discussion of this issue here: [How can I access the DOM elements within an iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603580/how-can-i-access-the-dom-elements-within-an-iframe/24603642#24603642)

Comment: @jfriend00 ty. I am a noob to node and embedded iframes so i'll definitely be looking into this.

Comment: jfriend00, iframe load and ready events do not work. they trigger immediately even when the iframe is not finished loading