# Firefox throws cross-origin error on iframe with same-origin PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, firefox, iframe, cross-origin-resource-policy

I have an iframe that's set to display a PDF loaded from the same origin.

```html
<iframe id="pdfIframe" src="/example.pdf"></iframe>
```

When I run this JS to check if the iframe is loaded yet, I get a `SecurityError` or `DOMException` in Firefox:

```js
iframeReady(document.getElementById('pdfIframe'), () => {
  console.log('iframe loaded')
))

/**
 * Execute callback when iframe is *actually* loaded. Ignores load events for
 * the "dummy" document that's loaded when an iframe is added to the DOM, and
 * before the src is loaded.
 *
 * Adapted from an answer on StackOverflow:
 * https://stackoverflow.com/a/24603642/877574
 */
function iframeReady(iframe, fn) {
  checkLoaded()

  function checkLoaded() {
    const doc = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow?.document
    // We can tell if there is a dummy document installed because the dummy document
    // will have an URL that starts with "about:".  The real document will not have that URL
    if (doc && doc.URL.indexOf("about:") !== 0) {
      // set event listener for DOMContentLoaded on the new document
      doc.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", fn)
    } else {
      // still same old original document, so keep looking for content or new document
      setTimeout(checkLoaded, 1)
    }
  }
}
```

I know one may think perhaps the error is occurring because the JS runs while the iframe has loaded `about:blank`. But I've verified that's not the case. After the iframe has loaded the PDF I can run this and it triggers the exception:

```js
pdfIframe.contentDocument // null
pdfIframe.contentWindow.document // triggers exception
```

The same code works in Chrome.

Comment: Do other browsers work?

Comment: @JaromandaX yeah it works in Chrome

Comment: @KJ that would only happen if you were loading from a file-system address (shows in address bar as `file://...`). The real code is running on an actual `https` website. And it doesn't matter where on the same origin the PDF is being loaded from as long as it's same origin.

Comment: no JS query involved - and I'm not sure why you're talking about PDF plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the built-in pdf viewer in Firefox to load a pdf, the iframe ends up with `domain === "pdf.js"` - therefore it is not same origin as the parent, therefore the issue.

There are issues relating to this in Mozilla's bugzilla - but the MAIN (or only) talking point is the inability to call `.print()` to print the PDF in an iframe

This is apparently at least partially addressed - e.g. `pdfIframe.contentWindow.print()` works.

There are also *some* other methods/properties are also available, but not `document`

One solution is to

- download `pdf.js` (it's a zip containing files by the way, it's not a single JS file) from https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/getting_started/#download
- extract the contents into a folder, let say `pdf`

Then, your iframe should use

```
<iframe 
  id="pdfIframe"
  src="/pdf/web/viewer.html?file=/example.pdf"></iframe>
```