# trying to use console of a new window

Tags: javascript, window.open, console.log

I'm beginner to learn JS and I am stuck with the following function.

I'm trying to open a new window and print in the console of the new window.
 My code is as follows:Can you please tell me where's the error ?

```
var newWindow = window.open("url");
newWindow.onload = function (newWindow) {
  newWindow.console.log("...something...");
}
```

Comment: Why do you need to access the `console` of the new window?

Comment: `newWindow.onload = function (){
                       console.log("...something...");
}`
try it

Comment: I believe this post is a possible [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589963/window-to-window-communication-in-js-by-window-name).

Comment: @gypsyCoder doesn't seem to work :(

Comment: is it throwing any error?

Comment: @AdamAzad my project requires me to do so.

Comment: @gypsyCoder nope, it is not !

Answer (score 1):

After the code

```
var newWindow = window.open("url");
```

It should instantly open another window with "url" path.  What happens after is field of work of "url" page. In this page you should have on document ready function which is similar to

```
newWindow.onload = function (newWindow) {
    newWindow.console.log("...something...");
}
```

Which could be simple jQuery function

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<html>
<script>
function myFunction() {
var myWindow = window.open("", "MsgWindow", "width=200, height=100");
myWindow.document.write("<p>This is 'MsgWindow'. I am 200px wide and 100px tall!</p>");
}
myFunction();
</script>
</html>
```

Write this code in a HTML file and run it, make sure pop-ups are not blocked.

Answer (score 1):

The result you want to get from the code is not possible. Let's call the window where you are executing javascript `window 1` and you are opening a fresh new window `window 2`. Now, `window 2` neither has reference of your js code nor has the `onload` event. onload event of `window 2` is firing at `window 1` instance. So, you are getting the console log at `window 1` instance not in `window 2`.

See the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/408sn8Lf/)'s console for `window 1` instance.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to create a new window with the same domain (or no url), you can use the console just fine:

```
var newWindow = window.open("");
newWindow.console.log("test");
```

Example: https://jsfiddle.net/8p2fk4j0/ (disable popup blocking)