# Display text/code in new opening window in Console Panel Chrome with only Javascript

Tags: javascript, console.log, window.open

This is the same question like [trying to use console of a new window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34575107/trying-to-use-console-of-a-new-window).

my project requires me to do so and i need solution:

For example:

```
var popup = window.open("https://www.google.de");

popup.alert("Hello GOOGLE!"); // this work fine!

popup.console.log("Hello Google!"); //  this won't display in Console Panel Chrome!
```

How can i get using only with Javascript to put some text in opening window and display in Console Panel?

Please enlighten me!

Comment: Do you control the site you are opening in the new window?

Comment: Hello Shyam Babu, no, i don't controll this website. I don't wish to control, only to insert some text in Input tag!

Comment: I don't think that use case is possible. That would be a security violation. Imagine if you opened a site and it opened your Facebook and started posting on you behalf. If you are looking for automation look at protractor or chrome drivers. but the above one will not possible.

Comment: Okay, i understand. thank you very much for your reply.